# Using If Statements With Defaults?

Tags: iphone, objective-c, if-statement

I have just watched a tutorial on how to setup defaults and was wondering about outputting the values of the defaults to text. My question is: can I use a default in an if statement. I tried with this:

```
-(IBAction)press {
cruzia.hidden = 0;
textarea.hidden = 0;
if ([defaults stringForKey:kMusic]) == YES {
    CFBundleRef mainBundle = CFBundleGetMainBundle();
    CFURLRef soundFileURLRef;
    soundFileURLRef =CFBundleCopyResourceURL(mainBundle, (CFStringRef) @"click", CFSTR ("wav"), NULL);
    UInt32 soundID;
    AudioServicesCreateSystemSoundID(soundFileURLRef, &soundID);
    AudioServicesPlaySystemSound(soundID);
```

But it didn't work. It said "Use of undeclaired identifier 'defaults'" and 'expected expression' I tried moving the code to below the declaration of 'defaults' yet that made no difference. I hope someone can reply!

Comment: Show the declaration and initialisation of defaults.

Comment: That code doesn't look like it will compile.

Comment: Please learn how to program before you attempt any more stuff with Objective-C.  Start with C or Java.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are many problems with the above code.  First of all, let me point out that neither the if statement nor the function have closing brackets.  Then, the `== YES` is outside of the parentheses.  Next, you are trying to compare an instance of `NSString` to a boolean.  Finally, neither `defaults` nor `kMusic` have been declared.

So here is some fixed code:

```
-(IBAction)press {
cruzia.hidden = 0;
textarea.hidden = 0;

defaults = [NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults];
//if defaults has been instantiated earlier and it is a class variable, this won't be necessary.
//Otherwise, this is part of the undeclared identifier problem



/*the other part of the undeclared identifier problem is that kMusic was not declared.
I assume you mean an NSString instance with the text "kMusic", which is how I have modified the below code.
If kMusic is the name of an instance of NSString that contains the text for the key, then that is different.

also, the ==YES was outside of the parentheses.
Moving that in the parentheses should fix the expected expression problem*/
if ([defaults boolForKey:@"kMusic"] == YES) {

    CFBundleRef mainBundle = CFBundleGetMainBundle();
    CFURLRef soundFileURLRef;
    soundFileURLRef =CFBundleCopyResourceURL(mainBundle, (CFStringRef) @"click", CFSTR ("wav"), NULL);
    UInt32 soundID;
    AudioServicesCreateSystemSoundID(soundFileURLRef, &soundID);
    AudioServicesPlaySystemSound(soundID);
    }
}
```

Now before you just copy and past that replacing your old code, you should understand the assumptions I made.  I am assuming that `defaults` has *not* previously been declared and instantiated.  Finally, I am assuming that you are looking for a boolean value that is stored with the string key "kMusic", so somewhere else in your code you use something like `[[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] setBool:true forKey:@"kMusic"];`  If that's not quite what you had in mind, you will need to make changes accordingly.

Finally, next time, reread your code for typos before bringing it to Stack Overflow.

Comment: Here's a link to apple docs which you should read through before continuing: http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/cocoa/Conceptual/UserDefaults/Introduction/Introduction.html "Preferences and Settings Programming Guide"

Answer (score 2):

Replace defaults with `[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults]`.  But if you are asking for a string back, you can't compare it to a boolean.  But you can store booleans in the userDefaults using `setBool:forKey:` and `boolForKey:`

Comment: Thanks @KHansenSF! I am trying to try that but I don't exactly get how to put it in code. This is my failed attempt: if ([[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] stringForKey:kMusic]) == YES {
        CFBundleRef mainBundle = CFBundleGetMainBundle();
       CFURLRef soundFileURLRef;
        soundFileURLRef =CFBundleCopyResourceURL(mainBundle, (CFStringRef) @"click", CFSTR ("wav"), NULL);
        UInt32 soundID;
        AudioServicesCreateSystemSoundID(soundFileURLRef, &soundID);
        AudioServicesPlaySystemSound(soundID);

Comment: please edit the question if you want to add code no one wants to read the mess that made in the comments.